# Does $\mathbb Q[a+b\sqrt n]$ satisfy Archimedean property?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Does $\mathbb Q[a+b\sqrt n]$ satisfy Archimedean property when n is squarefree and the inequality relation defines as lexicographic order as below.

Let $x=a+b\sqrt n$, $y=c+d\sqrt n$, so $b\ge d\implies x\ge y$. And if $b=d$ and $a\ge c$, then $x\ge y$.

Then does this satisfy Archimedean property? I guess that this doesn't, but I couldn't show that. Is my guess right? If not, could you tell me why it satisfy Archimedean prorperty?

Comment: So in your peculiar ordering, $\sqrt n>a$ for all $a\in\Bbb Z$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, I think it is.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Oh, I see. It's so trivial... Thank you:)